# How to inject dynamic secret parameters from Jenkins job execute shell script

Tags: jenkins, dynamic, passwords, mask

I am working on jenkins, which has dropdownlist/select list load with set MQ broker details. Each broker have different passwords stored in AWS secrets manger. I have written shell script to fetch password AWS secrets manager, i can able to get the password in **execute shell** build step.
I tried using mask passwords plugin-> mask passwords and regex, i am using same variable(BR_PASSWORD) defined in mask password option, even in shell script also.
What i provided default value with variables defined in global or password parameter , for default value.

All these options masking defined in default password in console output. But values which are coming trough shell script dynamically is not masking in console out put.

Answer (score -1):

please add an example of your code.
And use groove string `'command '` for mask passwords

```
sh '$password'
```